# DocumentDB JavaScript API: queryDatabases is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am creating a service for Azure Functions written in JavaScript/Node.js and I am getting the below error when attempting to access the function DocumentClient.queryDatabases. I have the correct references installed in Visual Studio Code and through Intellisense can see the queryDatabases method through the following:

```
var client = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;
client.queryDatabases(...);
```

Any ideas why the debugger is blowing up with the error?

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
TypeError: client.queryDatabases is not a function
    at Object.getOrCreateDatabase (/Users/.../Documents/.../UserModel.js:23:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../Documents/.../Test.js:5:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:638:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
```

[image: References]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to initialize the client with your DocumentDB host and auth key. And then call the function via this client.

Example:

```
var DocumentDBClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;

var endpoint = '<host>';
var primaryKey = '<authKey>';
var client = new DocumentDBClient(endpoint, { masterKey: primaryKey });

var querySpec = {
    query: 'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE  r.id = @id',
    parameters: [
        {
            name: '@id',
            value: databaseId
        }
    ]
};

client.queryDatabases(querySpec).toArray(function (err, results) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
});
```